# How to avoid many "$routeProvider.when" in a large application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

Is there a way to write a method which will parse the coming $location.path and load a specific html template OR apply a $route. Currently I have this long list of "Whens" for my application that will double or triple after completion.

```
 .config(['$routeProvider',
 function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      //Home
      //User/Tenant/Register
   when('/register', { templateUrl: 'pages/Auth/register.html' }).
   when('/login', { templateUrl: 'pages/Auth/login.html' }).
      //User
   when('/user', { templateUrl: 'pages/User/list.html' }).
   when('/user/new', { templateUrl: 'pages/User/new.html' }).
   when('/user/:userId', { templateUrl: 'pages/User/detail.html' }).
   when('/user/edit/:userId', { templateUrl: 'pages/User/new.html' }).
         //Role
   when('/role', { templateUrl: 'pages/Role/list.html' }).
   when('/role/new', { templateUrl: 'pages/Role/new.html' }).
   when('/role/:roleId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Role/detail.html' }).
   when('/role/edit/:roleId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Role/new.html' }).
   when('/roleassign', { templateUrl: 'pages/Role/assign.html' }).
   when('/roledefine', { templateUrl: 'pages/Role/define.html' }).
        //Permissions
   when('/permission', { templateUrl: 'pages/Permission/list.html' }).
   when('/permission/new', { templateUrl: 'pages/Permission/new.html' }).
   when('/permission/:permissionId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Permission/detail.html' }).
   when('/permission/edit/:permissionId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Permission/new.html' }).
   when('/permissionassign', { templateUrl: 'pages/Permission/assign.html' }).
      //Counter
   when('/X', { templateUrl: 'pages/Counter/list.html' }).
   when('/X/new', { templateUrl: 'pages/Counter/new.html' }).
   when('/X/:counterId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Counter/detail.html' }).
   when('/X/edit/:counterId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Counter/new.html' }).
      //Company
   when('/Y', { templateUrl: 'pages/Y/list.html' }).
   when('/Y/new', { templateUrl: 'pages/Y/new.html' }).
   when('/Y/:companyId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Y/detail.html' }).
   when('/Y/edit/:companyId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Y/new.html' }).
      //Product
   when('/Z', { templateUrl: 'pages/Z/list.html' }).
   when('/Z/new', { templateUrl: 'pages/Z/new.html' }).
   when('/Z/:productId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Z/detail.html' }).
   when('/Z/edit/:productId', { templateUrl: 'pages/Z/new.html' }).
   otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/index',
       templateUrl: 'pages/dashboard.html'
   });
  //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1: Separate config scripts

Instead of having a single configuration, you can have several. If that helps maintainability I'd separate individual groups into their own, so one can manage a subset at a time and make things mode manageable.
It seems your application uses folders to separate particular functionality groups. The same can be done with these config script files. They could be contained with their group of scripts.

### Solution 2: DRY code

It seems quite many *whens* in your code share some common conventions that could be refactored so only one block would be run for all of them without repeating the same code over and over again.

```
angular.foreach([
        "user",
        "permission",
        "role",
        "X",
        "Y",
        ...
    ], function(value) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/" + value, { templateUrl: "pages/" + value + "/list.html" })
        .when("/" + value + "/new", { ... })
        .when("/" + value + "/:" + value + "Id", { ... }),
        .when("/" + value + "/edit/:" + value + "Id", { ... })
});
```

But as I usually implement a simplified `string.prototype.format` function in Javascript to help with string concatenation, I'd write these lines as:

```
angular.foreach([
        "user",
        "permission",
        "role",
        "X",
        "Y",
        ...
    ], function(value) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/{0}".format(value), { templateUrl: "pages/" + value + "/list.html" })
        .when("/{0}/new".format(value), { ... })
        .when("/{0}/:{0}Id".format(value), { ... }),
        .when("/{0}/edit/:{0}Id".format(value), { ... })
});
```

For those groups that define additional routes I can see a similar pattern that could as well be refactored (ie. *roles* also have *define* and *assign*). In my previous code example I've only provided an array of string values. These could be changed to provide an object with properties being set to arrays with additional actions that they require and process those in iterator function.

```
angular.forEach({
    user: [],
    role: ["assign", "define"],
    permission: ["assign"],
    ...
}, function(actions, key) {
    // same 4 as above by using "key" instead of "value"
    $routeProvider
        .when("/{0}".format(key), { ... })
        ...;
    // if element has additional actions, configure those as well
    angular.forEach(actions, function(action) {
        $routeProvider.when("/{0}{1}".format(key, action), { ... });
    });
});
```

### Simplified `string.prototype.format` implementation

```
String.prototype.format = String.prototype.format || function () {
    ///<summary>Replaces placeholders in string with provided parameters.</summary>

    "use strict";

    var args = arguments;

    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, index) {
        return typeof (args[index]) != "undefined" ? args[+index] : "";
    });
};
```

Comment: A through answer. Can you share your string.prototype.format code?

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch: here you go... See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using ngRoute, but uiRouter, and I have implemented this solution in my last app. It looks like this: (in CoffeeScript, hovewer):

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config ($stateProvider) ->

    $stateProvider
    .state 'main.page',
    url: '/page/{staticName:[a-z0-9_]*}'
    templateUrl: (stateParams) ->
        '/views/page/' + stateParams.staticName + '.html'
    controller: 'PageCtrl'
```

Maybe it is possible in the same way in ngRouter?...